# Unable to restore 100% of dump.rdb keys in redis-stack-server container

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-stack-server

I am using redis-stack-server container image, and it is getting stopped after loading the data from dumb.rdb. I am doing backup from on-prem server and restoring it in docker container locally.

Trying to restore a backup data in redis-stack-server. I modified redis-stack.conf with the below code

```
port 6379
daemonize no
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir /data/
loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/rediscompat.so
loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisearch.so
loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/redistimeseries.so
loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/rejson.so
loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisbloom.so
loadmodule /opt/redis-stack/lib/redisgears.so v8-plugin-path /opt/redis-stack/lib/libredisgears_v8_plugin.so
```